# Dynamically load data uitableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am building a single viewcontroller app using UITableViewController in Swift 2.

The problem I am having here is if I load data inside viewDidLoad function, the UITableView displays well with the data.

However, I am trying to have get this data from a custom delegate method, which is called after the data is saved into core data, then self.tableview.reloadData() the UITableView won't display the data.

From my debugging, looks like the 

`override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int`

and 

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

run before my custom delegate method

```
func didReceiveQualifications(qualifications: [Qualification]) {   
    print("didReceivedQualifications")
    self.qualifications = qualifications

    // Pass qualification to view
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: That code and setup should actually work... Have you added `print`-statements to the two methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` as well to see at what time they get called? It is perfectly normal for them to get called before your delegate methods comes up. **But** they should be called once again after you do `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Additionally you might want to show the contents of the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` function.

Comment: I know it doesn't give you a proper answer but have you considered using NSFetchedResultsController? It makes the bridge between Core data objects and a UITableViewController for you. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be depend by where `didReceiveQualifications()` has launched..in which thread running..

All updates to the UI should be done in the main thread.

Try to make reloadData to the main thread:

```
func didReceiveQualifications(qualifications: [Qualification]) {   
    print("didReceivedQualifications")
    self.qualifications = qualifications

    // Pass qualification to view
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, this works, however, if I start scrolling the UITableView, all the data will disappear

Comment: Have you any part in your code where you override the scrollViewDidScroll method, check it. Probably your code launch didReceiveQualifications at the end of the scroll to update datas, right?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, I actually found out that 

self.qualifications[indexPath.row].name starts return nil when I start scroll

I didn't override scrollViewDidScroll method
here is my code https://github.com/ankermarco/gojimo/blob/master/Gojimo/QualificationTableViewController.swift

Comment: Apart from adding this code 'self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 45.0' at the end of  'viewDidLoad' i cannot see any problems, have you check constraints of your cell?, try to set a prefixed constraint cell HEIGHT